# why this java code takes less space and time compared to cpp

Tags: java, c++, memory, runtime

```
class Solution {
public:
    void inorder(TreeNode* root, int low, int high, int& res){
        if(root != nullptr){
            inorder(root->left, low, high, res);
            if(root->val <= high && root->val >= low){
                res += root->val;
            }
            inorder(root->right, low, high, res);
        }
    }
    int rangeSumBST(TreeNode* root, int low, int high) {
        int res=0;
        inorder(root, low, high, res);
        return res;
    }
};
```

Java:

```
class Solution {
    int res;
    public void inorder(TreeNode root, int low, int high){
        if(root != null){
            inorder(root.left, low, high);
            if(root.val <= high && root.val >= low){
                res += root.val;
            }
            inorder(root.right, low, high);
        }
    }
    public int rangeSumBST(TreeNode root, int low, int high) {
        res = 0;
        inorder(root, low, high);
        return res;
    }
}
```

[image: Leetcode Problem 938]

Leetcode Problem 938. Question is to find the Range sum of BST [low, high]

I am doing pretty much same in both languages(I guess but I am new to java), but how is the java code so fast compared to cpp is it something related to pointers and reference or the compiler which the site uses?
Regards

Comment: How did you compile the C++? Did you turn optimizations on? And how are you timing it all?

Comment: I am on leetcode it shows runtime and memory by itself rest I have no idea about what you are asking i dont know optimization and stuff yet

Comment: maybe the site is bugged?

Comment: Optimization is good stuff to learn before you spend much time on competing. It's pretty much all about optimizing and knowing how to abuse the compiler. Could be the JIT compiler is smart enough to see a way to eliminate all of the work. Hard to be sure exactly what is happening unless you know the judging system fairly well. And the top competitors will.

Comment: any resource where I can manually check the runtime of my code?

Comment: https://quick-bench.com/ Take a bit of reading and practice to figure out, but time well spent. Might be a few other similar tools out there, but this is the first one to pop into my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit research I found it is related to the platform itself. [Leetcode: Is java faster than C++](https://leetcode.com/discuss/general-discussion/136635/is-java-faster-than-c)

According to one comment "they remove compile and other procedure runtime from the benchmark for Java.
Which means for C/C++ solutions, compile time was counted in the runtime"
Not sure how much dependable this is.

Comment: It's not true. C++ compile time is also not taken into account.

Comment: Either way, generalizing from the comparative performance on Leetcode to anything else is ... misguided.  It is like comparing apples with apples by rolling them down a hill :-)   For the record, it is very difficult to get a valid "apples vs apples" comparison between Java and C++.

Comment: Yup, makes sense.